# Target name in Makefile prerequisite

Tags: makefile

I have some rules like this

```
foo_%: $(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
    gcc stuff
```

Directory variables like this:

```
BIN_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$@/$(TARGET)/bin
```

And a rule to make the directories:

```
$(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

I want the (expanded) `foo_%` part to replace the `$@`in the directory name, but right now `$@` gets replaced with nothing.

Now I could just replace `$@` with `%` in the BIN_DIR var:

```
    BIN_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/%/$(TARGET)/bin
```

but this omits the `foo_` part, which I do want to include.

Last resort is including three `mkdir -p` statements in each rule, but I'd rather not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expansion cannot work because the lists of prerequisites and targets in rules are expanded when the syntax is processed. In other words, statically, at the "compile time" of the makefile rules. Whereas the `$@` parameter is dynamic; it takes on values in the makefile "run time", when the rule tree is evaluated. At that time, it cannot be substituted into targets and prerequisites.

Since this is for just ensuring that some directories exist, you can move the `make -p` into the recipe, and do it like this. Note that we still have to change the `BIN_DIR :=` assignment into the non-expanding `BIN_DIR =` assignment:

```
TARGET := target
LIB_DIR := lib_dir
OBJ_DIR := obj_dir
BUILD_DIR := build_dir

BIN_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/$@/$(TARGET)/bin

foo: | $(LIB_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)  # see text below for explanation of | symbol
        mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
        echo other steps

$(LIB_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
        mkdir -p $@
```

Here, we are using the make rule processing to create `$(LIB_DIR)` and `$(OBJ_DIR)`. But `$(BIN_DIR)` is handled in a pedestrian way, just by running a `mkdir -p` in the recipe.  The expansion of `$@` works here because `BIN_DIR` is an traditional unexpanded-style make variable which undergoes expansion when it is substituted. It is still statically expanded when the rule syntax is processed, but the point is that it holds the unexpanded `$@` which is inserted into the `make -p` recipe line. Because that `$@` is in the recipe line, it works. It just doesn't work in the list of targets or prerequisites.

I used the `|` symbol to designate `$(LIB_DIR)` `$(OBJ_DIR)` as order-only prerequisites. [Read about this in the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html). Order-only prerequisites are only updated if they are missing. If they already exist, they are disregarded.

If we don't make these directories order-only, then they will trigger a rebuild of the target each time their time-stamp changes such that it is newer than the target.

It's probably best not to name directories as prerequisites anyway, and just put in the just-in-case `mkdir -p` into the recipe. As in, simply:

```
TARGET := target
LIB_DIR := lib_dir
OBJ_DIR := obj_dir
BUILD_DIR := build_dir

BIN_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/$@/$(TARGET)/bin

foo:
        mkdir -p $(LIB_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
        echo other step
```

Run:

```
$ make
mkdir -p lib_dir obj_dir build_dir/foo/target/bin
echo other steps
other steps
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot. So why can we have `%` in `$(BUILD_DIR)` but not `$@`? Isn't `%` no less dynamic than `$@` (or even the only dynamic part of the target)?

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich    `%` in target/prerequisite lines is special; it is the basis for pattern rules.  E.g. `%.o: %c:` a rule that will be used to make a `.o` from `.c` if no other more specific rule is found for the given object.

Comment: Hmm then it seems odd to me that we can get the matching portion of the target, but not the entire target. Seems like an oversight!

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich Shrug. It think the architecture is that none of the special variables like `$<`, `$^` or `$@` (GNU Make has quite a few more) get established until a rule is identified for a target, and kicked off. The pattern rule algorithm simply doesn't use them.